# Shadow Effects with QGraphicsRectItem in Qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsRectItem over a scene. I intend to drag and drop this window over the scene. When the rect item reaches the left boundary end I have to show it appearing from the right end. Currently I am using two objects and hiding and showing them by calculating the boundary of scene which involves lot of calculations. 
Is there any better way to achieve the same effect using just a single object?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single item that spans the entire scene, and draw the rectangle (or 2 parts of  it) in it's paint method.

But then you would lose the optimization of the BSP tree, your item would redraw even if some unrelated area repaints. If this is just 1 item, I guess it would not have much impact.

You would need to implement your own dragging with mousemove event and the like, though this is not much code, you just need to get it right.